# Excel : adding a value from a different column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have column a, b and c.
Where c matches with a, I want b to populate itself in d.

Does anyone know how to do this??

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! What have you tried? Learn the [IF function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2).

Comment: Excel does not do magic. You have to use VBA for this... what have you tried?

Comment: Could you please share us with a simple sample? If "match" means that the data in column C and column A are exactly the same, you can refer to Isolated's reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an IF formula to achieve this.

Cell D2 formula:

```
=IF(A2=C2,B2,"")
```

If A = C, then show B, else show nothing. Drag it down, done.

[image: Excel Worksheet]